# [__NSCFString reloadData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, reloaddata, unrecognized-selector

I've been having trouble adding items to a mutable array and getting those items to populate a UITableView.  They currently populate just fine, but after I add one item I get "Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance" on the `[reloadData];` call.  I've tried it in a number of different configurations but I cannot seem to get it to work.  When I disable reloadData it adds multiple items to the array without issue, but the moment I bring it back is when I get the same error.  This is the code that I'm working with:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

switch (alertView.tag)
{
    case 0:
        _FiltrationString = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        [_tankFilterArray addObject:_FiltrationString];
        NSLog(@"Number of Filtration Parts Added: %lu", (unsigned long)_tankFilterArray.count);
        break;
    case 1:
        _LightsString = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        [_tankLightsArray addObject:_LightsString];
        NSLog(@"Number of Lights Added: %lu", (unsigned long)_tankLightsArray.count);
        break;
    case 2:
        _MovementString = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        [_tankMovementArray addObject:_MovementString];
        NSLog(@"Number of Water Movement Added: %lu", (unsigned long)_tankMovementArray.count);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
[_tankFiltration reloadData];
[_tankLights reloadData];
[_tankMovement reloadData];
}
```

*ADDITIONAL CODE*

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

switch (tableView.tag)
{
    case 0:
        _tankFiltration = [_tankFilterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [_tankFilterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    case 1:
        _tankLights = [_tankLightsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [_tankLightsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    case 2:
        _tankMovement = [_tankMovementArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [_tankMovementArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    case 3:
        [self performSelector:@selector(saveButton)];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView.tag == 0)
{
    // MAKE FILTRATION TAG HERE
    return _tankFilterArray.count;
}
if (tableView.tag == 1)
{
    // MAKE LIGHTS TAG HERE
    return _tankLightsArray.count;
}
if (tableView.tag == 2)
{
    // MAKE MOVEMENT TAG HERE
    return _tankMovementArray.count;
}

NSLog(@"Tank Movement Array Items: %lu", (unsigned long)_tankMovementArray.count);
NSLog(@"Tank Lights Array Items: %lu", (unsigned long)_tankLightsArray.count);
NSLog(@"Tank Filtration Array Items: %lu", (unsigned long)_tankFilterArray.count);

return _tankMovementArray.count;
return _tankLightsArray.count;
return _tankFilterArray.count;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
return self;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? I've had a few people take a look at it on my side and no one can figure it out.  I appreciate the help in advance as always.  This issue is proving to be a cascading problem that permeates throughout the rest of my app and makes it difficult for testing.

*Updated Edit*

Fixed it!

The problem was in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Specifically:

```
            _tankFiltration = [_tankFilterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Was redeclaring the UITableView as an array.  I can't believe I didn't see it before.  Thank you so much everyone!

Comment: we may need a bit more code... basically it's telling you that _tankFiltration is a String (not a table or collection)... do you have more code taht deals with _tankFiltration?

Comment: Please provide more code, it isn't enough to understand your issue.

Comment: You need to post more code. One or more of _tankFiltration, _tankLights, and _tankMovement is an NSString, not a UITableView.

Comment: Added more code.  Let me know if you want to see more.  _filtrationString is an NSString that's being added to the array _tankFilterArray.

Comment: You're assigning a string to `_tankFiltration` here:  `_tankFiltration = [_tankFilterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` and then calling `reloadData` on it later... why are you using it as a string and a table view at the same time?

Comment: We also need the lines where are defined `tankFiltration`, etc. And you're setting a NSString to it. That's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If _FiltrationString is an NSString you should be using this command:

```
  _FiltrationString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text]; 
  [_tankFilterArray addObject:_FiltrationString];
```

instead of

```
       _FiltrationString = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
```

The command equates _FiltrationString to the address of the alert view textfield.

Comment: Tried this, same result as before.

Comment: its odd that you have 3 reloaddata statements - I didn't see your latest update but reload data is a trigger to call a series of tableview delegate methods including cellforrowatindexpath, so you only need to do a reload data on your active tableview what is - _tankFiltration. =tanklight, and _tankmovement ?  How many tableviews do you have?

Comment: The trouble is that I have 3 reloadData calls because there are three separate tableViews.  All of which have separate arrays attached to them.  That's why I called each one to reload after the collection of the string from the alertView.

Comment: Just asking  - Your use of the "="sign is troubling if I do this  ->  _tankFiltration = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;  - I will effectively change my tableview into an NSCFstriong object. and it will create the error message above.

Comment: Here's how it breaks down:  each tableView has an array and a string added to that array.  Each is declared in the header file and called in the implementation file, and the naming convention is consistent.  For example: `_tankFiltration`, `_tankLights`, and `_tankMovement` are tableViews.  Then `_tankFilterArray`, `_tankLightsArray`, and `_tankMovementArray` are the mutable arrays.  Strings are named appropriately as listed above.

Comment: I would check the tableviews and see if any of them are being recast as string objects ....  Its the simple errors that are very hard to find .

Comment: I would check the tableviews and see if any of them are being recast as string objects ....  Its the simple errors that are very hard to find .  Also since you only have 1 set of delegate methods 1 reloaddata should be enough  try putting a breakpoint  you will see that your 3 reload data effectively calls the same routine 3x

Comment: Double checking; the only time I reference the actual tableViews is listed above.  I can't find anywhere that they might be converted to strings.

Comment: `_tankFiltration = [_tankFilterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` how is this not assigning a string to a table view ivar?

Comment: THAT WAS IT! Can't believe I missed that

Comment: The problem is your cellforrowatindexpath - you are assigning a string to your tableviews not to your string. as indicated by carl.